# How do I change tk.Labelframe bordercolor by change value?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

def btn_cmd():
    a = test_ety.get()
    if a == '1':
        print("change test_lbl bordercolor red")
    elif a == '2':
        print("change test_lbl bordercolor grey")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("test Example")
root.geometry("500x200")

frm = tk.Frame(root)
frm.configure(width=500, height=500)
frm.place(x=0, y=0)

test_lbl = tk.LabelFrame(frm, text="import")
test_lbl.configure(width=350, height=30)
test_lbl.place(x=0, y=0)

test_ety = tk.Entry(test_lbl)
test_ety.configure(width=40)
test_ety.place(x=5, y=0)

test_btn = tk.Button(frm, text="button", command=btn_cmd)
test_btn.configure(width=30, height=1)
test_btn.place(x=50, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

How do I change tk.Labelframe bordercolor by change value?

If test_ety is get 1, test_lbl bordercolor change red,

and else if test_ety is get 2, test_lbl bordercolor change grey

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Changing border color for `tk.LabelFrame` seems not possible. But you can use `ttk.LabelFrame` instead. With some styling, it is possible to change the colors of the border and the label of it.

```py
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_create("test", settings = { 
    "TLabelframe": {
        "configure": {
            "background": "red",
            "borderwidth": 1
        }
    }
})
style.theme_use("test")
```

### Reference

- [ttk.LabelFrame](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-LabelFrame.html)
- [Customizing and creating ttk themes and styles](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-themes.html)

### Example

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_create("test", settings = { 
    "TLabelframe": {
        "configure": {
            "background": "red",
            "borderwidth": 1
        }
    }
})
style.theme_use("test")

sample = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Sample")
sample.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

lbl = ttk.Label(sample, text="Hello World")
lbl.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```